# FABRIK inverse kinematic

Tags: inverse-kinematics

[image]I was reading the FABRIK inverse kinematic that You can find more information here:  http://www.andreasaristidou.com/publications/papers/FABRIK.pdf

This paper suggests for each joint there is 4 value which constraint the rotational motion of that joint and constitutes a cone then Shows the composite ellipsoidal shape created by the distances q_j mapped from 3D to 2D. 
My question is how to determine the x,y coordinate of the 2D plane? I mean there is infinite coordinate system that passes from point "o" in the mentioned plane. How can I fix this coordinate system?